# package com.sun.beans.finder does not exist openjdk

Tags: java, package

When a file is compiled that imports `com.sun.beans.finder.ConstructorFinder`, this error comes out:

```
./src/Demo/FeatConstruction.java:14: error: package com.sun.beans.finder does not exist
```

The system is an Ubuntu 18.04.1 with OpenJDK:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
```

**Where can I find this package?**

The compilation process is as follows:

- Sources files are located in `src`
- Some jar dependencies are in `lib`
- The output classes are in `bin`

For `./src/Demo/FeatConstruction.java`, I compile it using:

```sh
javac -cp "./src:./lib" -d bin ./src/Demo/FeatConstruction.java
```

Comment: Could you describe the compilation process ? (scripts, tools, configuration)

Comment: Probably because you are using openjdk. Try using the Oracle version instead.

Comment: I added the compilation process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be trying to use this class in your code.  It is an internal class.  All classes in `com.sun.*` are notionally internal, and should not be used directly in your code.

The class exists in the OpenJDK codebase (Java 8, 11 and even 17), and is present in `rt.jar` in the OpenJDK Java 8 installation on my Ubuntu box.

But even so, my Java 8 `javac` is still saying that the package does not exist.  So I suspect that `javac` itself is black-listing the package.

There might be a workaround<sup>1</sup> for this, but my advice is DON'T DO IT.  Find another way to implement the functionality rather than relying on some undocumented internal class.  For example, look for a well written<sup>2</sup> 3rd-party library.

If you do find a way to make your code compile and run on Java 8, be aware that it is liable to stop working on later releases.  1) The class may be renamed or removed without notice.  2) In later versions, they are making it harder and harder to directly use JDK internal classes in your code.

If you persist with this **bad practice** you are stacking up *future* problems for yourself ... or the poor mug who has to maintain your code.

---

<sup>1 - ... but I doubt that switching to an Oracle Java 8 distro is going to help.

2 - A library that doesn't do this kind of bad stuff under the covers.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your concern on using internal classes. The project I'm working on was developed by someone else, no docs were included and I wanted to test it. You pointed out that the class is found in the `rt.jar` of the OpenJDK, in my case in `/usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java8-full-amd64`. VS Code do see the package, but when I try `javac -cp "/usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java8-full-amd64/jre/lib/*:./lib/*:./src" -d bin ./src/Demo/FeatConstruction.java`, the compiler still doesn't import the package.

Comment: If I copy `rt.jar` into the `lib` directory of the project, it compiles just fine.

Comment: 1) So, it is pretty clear that `javac` itself is blacklisting the package. 2) If it was me, I would be looking at alternatives to that project.  Or if I was the "mug", I'd be looking at ways to get rid of this harmful dependency.  (Your workaround probably won't work in Java 9+ because `rt.jar` goes away.)

Comment: I could guest so, the compiler blacklisting the package. Unfortunately there's no alternative to the project. A restructure could be done to replace all those internal blacklisted classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a trace of these classes here:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/docs/?api=com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder

From the package name I'd conclude they come from the times when Sun owned the Java stuff and thus are at most to be found in Oracle JDK - but not as the standard classes.

To lookup classes, you may want to switch to the standardized API.
For any Object (or derived class instance), run

```
Class objectClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Object");
```

With that you can also find classes by name and get class references back - and it is available on all Java implementations.